# Water in an unused dishwasher

Tags: plumbing, drain

We went on a 2 week vacation and returned to standing water in our empty dishwasher.We did use the kitchen sink for a couple days and just noticed when we started to fill dishwasher we had standing water. How come?

Comment: Can be a few reasons, but the concerning one would be the fill valve is getting weak and dripping/letting water in.

Comment: If you have a separate shutoff valve for the dishwasher, would think about using it when dishwasher not in use.  If not turn off the house/kitchen water if going away for some time.

Answer (score 4):

If there isn't an above-counter air gap on the dishwasher drain hose, it's quite common to have backflow from the sink drain (diswasher typically comes in above the trap, so no stink required) if the sink is filled and then the stopper pulled, for instance.

If the drain hose does not make a high loop to the underside of countertop level (what it should do if there isn't an air gap, but not rare for that to be ignored or changed after the fact) it won't even take filling the sink to the top to make it siphon back into the dishwasher.

Comment: It's amazing. I simply followed the installation instructions for both of my dishwashers _including_ running the drain hose up high, and have never had an issue with any sort of smells, back flow or anything. I mean, I know I'm a guy, but it _can_ actually be helpful to read the directions.

Answer (score 2):

That water can come from one of two places. The drain, but probably not as you did not notice any smell, or the feed valve. You can test it but it will take a few days:

- Close the water shutoff to it and try for a few seconds to put water
  in the dishwasher by cycling the controls, this will purge that line.
- Turn the power off or unplug it. Then dry it out and place some
  newspaper (makes it easier to see), close it and let it set for
  several days or until it gets wet.
- If it **gets wet** it is coming in from the **drain**.
- If it **stays dry**, open the **feed valve** and it should be wet in a
  few days.
- You can then remove the paper, turn the power on and decide what you want to do.

My recommendation is to replace the defective part. If it is the drain reinstall it properly. In my case it ruined the kitchen, cabinets, and the floor below when it leaked. We were in another part of the house for a few hours. Nothing appeared out of normal except it was getting a little warmer. The reason for that was that it drained the hot water tank.